# =IF(ISERR(SEARCH - removing characters from string

Tags: excel, string, sharepoint, excel-formula

I have a sharepoint list on which I have column processing to remove characters from one of the fields.

I need to go from: `["string1","string2"]`  to: `string1 string2`
i.e. two strings in the same field without the special characters.

I currently have:
`=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("[",Perms,1)),Perms,REPLACE(Perms,SEARCH("[",Perms,1),1,""))`

but this is only getting me halfway.   Can you help?

Comment: Depending on consistency of your string: `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)-4),""","""," ")`. Also I suppose your wanted result is not twice `string1`?

Comment: apologies, yes that was a typo.  i'll try your suggestion

Comment: sharepoint doesn't like the substitue - it coming back with syntax error.  it does however accept   =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Perms],SEARCH("[",[Perms]),1,""),SEARCH("]",[Perms]),1,""),SEARCH(",",[Perms]),1,""),SEARCH("]",[Perms]),1,"")   - i just can't figure out the logic

Comment: Right, Substitute isn't available in SharePoint but replace is not a good alternative since it's not a global replacement of a substring. You might need to use Find?